# Getting attachment from Smartsheet row and sending it to e-mail

Tags: smartsheet-api

Im struggling with this problem. I have a Smartsheet sheet. And an Attachment is added to this row (jpg,png,pdf). Now what I would like to do is when a new row is added or changed, an attachment(if there is any) gets sent to a specific e-mail address.

In Smartsheet you cant send directly an attachment, only link to it. Also in Microsoft Power Automate you cant even select this field with an attachment. It is not a regular column.

I dont know anything about coding, but I saw some post here that someone made an "API" in some program where you can do this. Is this possible?

Only thing that I can think of that would solve my problem is by coding it. So if anyone has ever done this, or know hot to do it, it would be great if you shared it.

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly possible to implement a solution for this scenario by using the [Smartsheet API](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs), but doing so would require a developer. IMO, it's not something that someone with no development background could realistically achieve.

However, it looks like you could use [Zapier](https://zapier.com) to address your scenario -- which wouldn't require any coding. (Zapier is a third-party tool/service, just like Power Automate.) I haven't ever used Zapier for this particular scenario, but a quick look at what's possible there makes it appear feasible:

[image: Zapier workflow]

** **UPDATE** **

Upon further investigation, Zapier may not fully address your scenario, as I'm not seeing a way to have Zapier attach the file (attachment) from Smartsheet to the email it sends. Therefore, it may be necessary to use the [Smartsheet API](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs) to build a custom solution -- but as stated previously, you'll likely need a developer to do this.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I have already looked into Zapier. Although it is a great tool, it does not have features to send attachments from Smartsheet.